# An unexplained condition on $a$ in a proof on the primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, proof-explanation

**Lemma**

> A positive integer $n$ is a prime if $(n,p) = 1$ for every prime integer $p \leq \sqrt{n}$

**Proof in my text**

Let $(n,p) = 1$ for every prime $p \leq \sqrt{n} \:$. Suppose $n$ is not a prime, we may write $n=ab$ with $1 < a \leq b \:$ , then $a \leq \sqrt {n} \:$. Any prime $p$ dividing $a$ also divides $n$ and we have $p \leq a \leq \sqrt {n} \:$, contradicting $(n,p) = 1$. Hence $n$ is a prime.

**My question**

I follow the proof, except the part where it is stated that $a \leq \sqrt {n} \:$. I just don't understand how this condition follows from $n = ab \rightarrow 1 < a \leq b$

Comment: Let's consider an additive analog. If $\,a+b = n\,$ then one of $\,a,b\,$ is $\le$ their average $\,n/2,\,$ and the other is $\ge n/2.\,$ Yours is a multiplicative analog using *geomertic* (vs arithmetic) mean, namely if $\,ab = n\,$ then one factor is $\le \sqrt n\,$ and the other is $\ge \sqrt n.\  \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque That's a nice way of putting it. Thanks.

Comment: We are give $a < b$ and $ab =n $.  Suppose $\sqt n < a <b $ then $ab > \sqrt n \sqrt n = n $.  A contradiction.  BTW this also shows $b \ge \sqrt n $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't understand a condition, it is generally a good idea to assume its opposite and see what goes wrong. In this case, $a > \sqrt n$ implies $b \ge a > \sqrt n$, hence $n = ab > n$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $a > \sqrt n$, then since $ a \leq b$: $$a \cdot b > \sqrt n \cdot \sqrt n = n$$
meaning $ab > n$, which is in contradiction with the original statement $n = ab$.